# How can i use Jmeter as a normal browser?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I am using jmeter for performance testing 
but jmeter only accept JS call they can not pass request like URL.
so my question is that how can i user jmeter as a normal browser for 
load testing ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

It is possible to [configure JMeter to behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) when it comes to normal [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) given you:

1. Tell JMeter to download embedded resources (scripts, styles, fonts, images, sounds, etc.) in parallel
2. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to mimic browser cache when it comes to handling the aforementioned embedded resources
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent browser cookies
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent browser headers

JMeter will not automatically kick off the requests triggered by JavaScript as it doesn't have full JavaScript runtime so you will have to add a separate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler per such a request. If you need to simulate several [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests - consider putting them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) as browsers execute AJAX request simultaneously